# Linkage problem when building program with libtorch on Raspberry PI

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, torch, libc, libtorch

I'm writing a C++ program using libtorch and OpenCV.

Here is the output of my `CMakeLists.txt`, with the libraries versions :

```
-- Pytorch status :
--     libraries: torch;torch_library;/usr/lib/libc10.so
-- OpenCV library status :
--     version: 3.2.0
--     libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_viz;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto
--     include path: /usr/include;/usr/include/opencv
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/<my_user>/<project>/cmake-build
```

You can see that torch needs `libc10.so` to work.

When I call `make`, everything goes fine, until this happens during linking :

```
[  8%] Linking CXX executable POC_V4
/usr/lib/libc10.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/POC_V4.dir/build.make:298: POC_V4] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/POC_V4.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:104: all] Error 2
```

When I do a `file` command on this file, I see that it is compiled for x86-64 architectures, instead of ARM.
Here is the output of the `file` command on `/usr/lib/libc10.so` and on `/usr/lib/libtorch.so.3.0.0` to have a comparison:

```
/usr/lib/libc10.so: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=f8019a46a003bc238af0fb3fb8331af8af69aa33, not stripped
/usr/lib/libtorch.so.3.0.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=2f8320292f01aab7c9e2e2577b3be2025689c0a7, stripped
```

How can I have a working libc10.so file ?

**EDIT:**

I started to re-build PyTorch on my raspberry PI so it would re-build libtorch too.
This takes many hours, and crashed during the night for a linkage problem :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_load_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_exchange_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_sub_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_compare_exchange_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [caffe2/CMakeFiles/conv_to_nnpack_transform_test.dir/build.make:108: bin/conv_to_nnpack_transform_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2836: caffe2/CMakeFiles/conv_to_nnpack_transform_test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_load_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_exchange_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_sub_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_compare_exchange_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [caffe2/CMakeFiles/depthwise3x3_conv_op_test.dir/build.make:108: bin/depthwise3x3_conv_op_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2867: caffe2/CMakeFiles/depthwise3x3_conv_op_test.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_load_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_exchange_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_sub_8'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<myuser>/pytorch_install/pytorch/build/lib/libcaffe2.so: undefined reference to `__atomic_compare_exchange_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [caffe2/CMakeFiles/pattern_net_transform_test.dir/build.make:108: bin/pattern_net_transform_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2805: caffe2/CMakeFiles/pattern_net_transform_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:161: all] Error 2
```

However, the build outputed a `libc10.so` file with the following signature!

```
/usr/lib/libc10.so: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=61d77cfaa9647739e17f6b08caeb53382d9e9108, not stripped
```

I replaced it in the `/usr/lib` folder and tried to build my project : It went further than before, and crashed for another file-format problem. This proves that if I manage to fully rebuild libtorch, I should be able to build my project !

Can someone help me solve the new linking problem ?

**EDIT #2:**

I found [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/22564) with the same problem. Trying the given solution and coming back here if that works to write a full tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work and detailed it in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755739/libtorch-on-raspberry-cant-load-pt-file-but-working-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment111011460_62755739).

Don't hesitate to improve it if you find errors / bad practices !

Answer (score 0):

I have found a link overcome the issue you are facing. Please read it through it should solve your solve.
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/14727

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, but the issue is about a MAC install, with x86-64 architecture. The `libc10` library in the files linked in this issue is in format `libtorch/lib/libc10.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 dynamically linked shared library, flags:<NOUNDEFS|DYLDLINK|TWOLEVEL|WEAK_DEFINES|BINDS_TO_WEAK|NO_REEXPORTED_DYLIBS|HAS_TLV_DESCRIPTORS>`, whereas I need ARM32 format : `/usr/lib/libc10.so: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=61d77cfaa9647739e17f6b08caeb53382d9e9108, not stripped`