# Libtorch on Raspberry can't load pt file but working on ubuntu

Tags: c++, build, raspberry-pi, torch, libtorch

I'm trying to build a C++ program with libtorch on a Raspberry PI. The program is working on Ubuntu, but I've got the following error at build on Raspberry :

```
error: use of deleted function â€˜void torch::jit::script::Module::operator=(const torch::jit::script::Module&)â€™
In file included from /usr/include/torch/csrc/jit/ir.h:18,
                 from /usr/include/torch/csrc/jit/tracer.h:9,
                 from /usr/include/torch/csrc/autograd/generated/variable_factories.h:8,
                 from /usr/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:7,
                 from /usr/include/torch/script.h:3,
                 from /tmp/tmp.k6618dczxt/src/../include/suvoNet.h:26,
                 from /tmp/tmp.k6618dczxt/src/../include/classifier.h:17,
                 from /tmp/tmp.k6618dczxt/src/classifier.cpp:11:
/usr/include/torch/csrc/jit/script/module.h:319:3: note: declared here
   TH_DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(Module);
```

Here is the code that crashes :

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
    try {
        // Deserialize the ScriptModule from a file using torch::jit::load().
        network = torch::jit::load(MODEL_FILE);
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error loading the model\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

With `network` declared private `torch::jit::script::Module network`

I build libtorch for Raspberry (ARM) using pyTorch from github in version '1.0.0a0+8322165'

Comment: Why are you using pytorch 1.0.0 version? Current is 1.5 and the first version where C++ API is stable. Maybe try the latest head (`1.7` IIRC, but should be stable, or checkout to `1.5.0`).

Comment: Hi, I started compiling 1.6.0 version 20h ago, it takes more than 24hours to compile, I'll give you a feedback tomorrow. If that doesn't work, I will try 1.5

Comment: Thank you @SzymonMaszke, the build worked on my Raspberry PI 4 (and the PI 3 is still building). I posted an answer with all my procedure and made it a community wiki. You can update it to improve it. I'm still a beginer in CMake / libtorch / C++, so there may be some bad practices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TLDR** : Compile libtorch in 1.6.0 and that works fine.

## How to compile Libtorch for Raspberry and use in my C++ Project ?

### Prepare to build

#### Increase RBPi SWAP

First of all, if you have a Raspberry PI 3 or lower, you need to increase the SWAP, since the build is a RAM eater.

> If you have a RBPi 4 or higher with more than 3GB of RAM, skip this step.

Modify the file `/etc/dphys-swapfile` :

```sh
CONF_SWAPFILE=2048M
```

Then call the following command to update changes.

```sh
sudo dphys-swapfile setup
```

#### Install base packages

Install the following packages:

```
sudo apt install build-essential make cmake git python3-pip libatlas-base-dev
```

Libtorch needs CMake>=`3.15` to be built properly, check cmake version with  cmake --version``

If it's lower than 3.15, follow the following commands to build a newer version and remove the previous one:

```
wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.18.0-rc1/cmake-3.18.0-rc1.tar.gz
tar -xzf cmake-3.18.0-rc1.tar.gz
cd cmake<version>
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install

sudo apt remove cmake
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/cmake /usr/bin/cmake
sudo ldconfig
```

### Building PyTorch from source to get libtorch backend for ARM

> Don't forget to increase the SWAP to 2048M if you don't have 3GB or RAM.

Getting all needed libraries:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Getting PyTorch sources:

```sh
git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch --branch=release/1.6
cd pytorch
```

Init all the submodules :

```sh
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule update --remote third_party/protobuf # To prevent a bug I had
```

Getting all needed libraries:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Getting PyTorch sources:

```sh
git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch --branch=release/1.6
cd pytorch
```

Setting up environment variables for the build.

Add the following lines to the `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export NO_CUDA=1
export NO_DISTRIBUTED=1
export NO_MKLDNN=1 
export NO_NNPACK=1
export NO_QNNPACK=1
```

Log in as root, and use the .bashrc file to setup the environment variables

```
sudo su
source /home/<user>/.bashrc
```

Install python dependencies

```
pip3 install setuptools pyyaml numpy
```

Build and install PyTorch, time to grab a :coffee:, it make take a while.

> Don't forget the `-E` that forces the environment variables to be used.

```sh
sudo -E python3 setup.py install
```

Check the installation worked:

```sh
cd 
python3
import torch
torch.__version__
```

### Building your program with Torch

In your `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(projectName)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/pi/pytorch/torch") # Adding the directory where torch as been installed
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) # C14 required to compile Torch
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
add_compile_definitions(_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0) # Torch is compiled with CXX11_ABI, so your program needs to be also, or you may have conflicts in some libraries (such as GTest for example)

# Specifying we are using pthread for UNIX systems.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -Wall")

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

if(NOT Torch_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Pytorch Not Found!")
endif(NOT Torch_FOUND)

message(STATUS "Pytorch status :")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "    Torch Flags: ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

# Program executable
add_executable(projectName <sources>)

target_link_libraries(projectName PRIVATE pthread dl util ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})
```